# multiple where statements in mysql query

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql query in my php which looks like this

```
$query1 = "SELECT time, air FROM pi_sensors_network WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'";
```

but now i want to include an additional where statement in my sql query which is

```
WHERE location = '".$location."'";
```

of course i also have my form

```
<form action="" method="get">
        Select Your location:
        <select name="location" onchange="javascript: submit()">
        <option>---</option>
        <option>FC3</option>
        <option>T12</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

as well as the php to get the location from my database

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['location']))
    {
    echo "<b>".$_POST['location']."</b><br><br>";
    }
?>


<?php
$location = 'FC3';

    if( isset($_GET['location'] ))
    {
        $location = $_GET["location"];
    }
?>
```

how do i include multiple where statements in my sql query?

Comment: You can use multiple `WHERE` in query using `AND`

Comment: You need to use conditional operators to join query conditions which depends on your logic. For example OR, AND, IN, BETWEEN full list here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: Is the method GET or POST? There both in this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AND` to perform multiple `WHERE` conditions in query. Try like this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT time, air 
FROM pi_sensors_network 
WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'
AND location = '".$location."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many `WHERE` clauses as you want using `AND` to separate.

*multiple where statements in mysql query*.

Do **not** put multiple `WHERE` clauses (in case you thought of it).

```
$query1 = "SELECT time, air FROM pi_sensors_network 
WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'" 
AND location = '".$location."'";
```

Or this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT time, air FROM pi_sensors_network 
WHERE location = '".$location."'" AND date BETWEEN '".$date1."' 
AND '".$date2."'";
```

> Note: Both would work, it only depends on the scenario/choice you
>   have.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more "where-statements" After the first WHERE-statement you write them as: AND

In your example:

```
SELECT time, air FROM pi_sensors_network 
WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'" 
AND location = '".$location."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If is set location, a new condition will insert in query, if not, empty.

```
if( isset($_GET['location'] ))
            {
                $location = $_GET["location"];
                $location_q = " AND location LIKE ".$location;
            } else 
            {
            $location_q = ""
            }
    $query1 = "SELECT time, air FROM pi_sensors_network WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2.$location_q"'";
```